# With PDO, how can I make sure that an UPDATE statement was successful?

Tags: php, mysql

It seems that for an INSERT statement, one can use `if (isset($connect->lastInsertId()))` in order to check whether the INSERT statement was successful. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

But for an UPDATE statement, how can I know if it was successful?

For example, I have  basic one like that:

```
$statement=$connect->prepare("UPDATE users SET premium='1' WHERE userid=?");
$statement->execute(array($id));
```

Thanks a lot in advance. Regards

Comment: What is a successful update statement in your eyes?

Comment: Hi, it's a statement that resulted in the modification of at least one  value in the table. Regards

Comment: `PDOStatement::rowCount()` returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object. See http://de.php.net/manual/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: There is not difference, whether it's SELECT, INSERT or UPDATE query. You check for a failure the same way

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "successful."  If you mean that the query executed without failing, then `PDO` will either throw an exception on failure or return `FALSE` from `PDOStatement::execute()`, depending on what error mode you have set, so a "successful" query in that case would just be one in which the execute method did not return `FALSE` or throw an exception.

If you mean "successful" in that there were actually rows updated (versus just 0 rows updated), then you'd need to check that using [`PDOStatement::rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php), which will tell you the number of affected rows from the previous query.

Warning: For updates where `newvalue = oldvalue` `PDOStatement::rowCount()` returns zero. You can use

> `$p = new PDO($dsn, $u, $p, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));`

in order to disable this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this. I actually meant "more than zero row updated". Regards

Comment: Very nice answer - I actually needed the first part - true/false :)

Comment: Pay attention relying on rowCount result: 
PDOStatement->rowCount — Returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement

If you try to update a row but the new field(s) value(s) are the same than the one(s) already stored in the DB, rowCount will return 0 (as nothing has been actually updated!).

This doesn't mean that that your UPDATE statement was not successfully executed!

Comment: @MarcoGagliardi this is the solution : http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#104930

Comment: @FtDRbwLXw6 could you advice what means `$dsn`, `$u` and `$p` in `$p = new PDO($dsn, $u, $p, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));`

Answer (score 16):

```
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if($count =='0'){
    echo "Failed !";
}
else{
    echo "Success !";
}
```

Comment: It will be better that you explain about your answer , Code only answers are not very helpful.

Comment: my answer is about UPDATE.

        $sql = "UPDATE users SET premium='1' WHERE userid=$id ";
        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

then the above code will echo success or failed.

Comment: rowCount returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement. So if the count is 0, then no rows were affected. Hence the update failed. I would remove the quotes around the number zero because the rowCount method returns an int. It will work anyway because you are not using triple equals to compare.