# Query update function not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following function from CS50 2014 and it's working when I SELECT but it's not working when I try to UPDATE. Here's the query and the function:

```
query(
    "UPDATE users 
         SET pwtxt = ?, pass = ?, dt = ?, reset = ?
         WHERE usr  = ?",
    NULL,
    "compass",
    NULL,
    0,
    1
);

function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */)
{

    // SQL statement
    $sql = func_get_arg(0); 

    // parameters, if any
    $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);  

    // try to connect to database
    static $handle;
    if (!isset($handle))
    {
        try
        {
            // connect to database
            $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL
            $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            // trigger (big, orange) error
            trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }
    }

    // prepare SQL statement
    $statement = $handle->prepare($sql);
    if ($statement === false)
    {
        // trigger (big, orange) error
        //  trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);  need to fix array issue
        exit;
    }   

    // execute SQL statement
    $results = $statement->execute($parameters);


    // return result set's rows, if any
    if ($results !== false)
    {       
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    else
    {       
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears you can no longer update with NULLS

Answer (score -1):

When your are Updating rows you can't use the *fetch* methods. That's why it's working only with *Select* queries.

[With PDO, how can I make sure that an UPDATE statement was successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820914/with-pdo-how-can-i-make-sure-that-an-update-statement-was-successful)

You have to use the *rowCount* method to see how many have been affected by your query. By the way I don't think it's a good idea to try to mix up different queries types in only one method. Return values for a *select*, an *update*, an *insert* or a *delete* are not the same. You can't sum up these in one same function.

If you want to centralize your database connection, I invite you to create a child class of PDO where you can hard code your DB credentials. Or you can create a global PDO object or better, use a singleton. That way, you will be able to use your PDO instance anywhere without duplicating your DB credentials all around and using PDO native methods for your preparations.

Comment: It only uses fetch if results != false.  The update works as written if you remove the nulls